# How to understand python data frames better

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Being a beginner in Python, I often face this problem - Let's say I am working with a data frame and want to execute an operation on one of the column. It can be just removing the decimal point from the value or maybe I want to take out the month from the date column. But often the solutions I would find online - it is generally shown with a single value or a data point like this:

```
a = 11.0
int(a)
11
```

Now, the same solution can't be applied if I have a data frame or a column. Again If I want to add time with date

```
d = date.today()
d
datetime.date(2018, 3, 30)

datetime.combine(d, datetime.min.time())
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 30, 0, 0)
```

In the same manner, this solution can not be used for a data frame. That will throw an error. Obviously I have a lacking in knowledge here, I am not being able to make it work in terms of data frames. Can you please point me towards the topic which might help me understand these problems in terms of data frames ? or maybe show an example how its done ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at *pandas* library to manipulate dataframes : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

This is an exemple to apply a function for each value of a given column:

```
import pandas as pd

def myFunction(a_string):
   return a_string.upper()

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

print(data)
data['City'] = data['City'].apply(myFunction)
print(data)
```

Data at beginning :

```
 Name     City    Age
 Robert   Paris   32
 Max      Dallas  24
 Raj      Delhi   27
```

Data after:

```
 Name     City    Age
 Robert   PARIS   32
 Max      DALLAS  24
 Raj      DELHI   27
```

Here myFunction uppercase the string but could be used the same way for other kind of operations.

Hope that helps.